# Can holders of Israeli residence visas enter area A in the West Bank?

Tags: legal, israel, israeli-citizens, palestine

I know that is is illegal for Israeli citizens to enter area A of the West Bank. However, foreign citizens that enter Israel are usually allowed to travel to such areas.

Are holders of an A1 visa (residence visa valid for 3 years) in a foreign passport covered under the ban on Israelis entering (such visa holders would have both an Israeli non-citizen-resident ID Card and a foreign passport)? Or does this ban exclusively apply to those who are citizens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a great post about this exact issue [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Under-Israeli-law-specifically-how-are-Israelis-restricted-from-visiting-the-Palestinian-Authority-area-s). To answer your questions...

> Since [October 2000](http://www.law.idf.il/Templates/GetFile/GetFile.aspx?FileName=XGF5b3NoLWRvY3NcdGFmcml0X2hha2lrYVx0emF2ZXlfc2dpcmF0X3NodGFoaW1cc2dpcmF0X3NoZXRhaF9lc3VyX2tuaXNhX2lzcmFlbGltX2V6dXJhLnBkZg%3D%3D&InfoCenterItem=true), a military warrant of a major general in the IDF central region command (Maj. Gen. Itzhak Eitan at the time) forbids Israelis from entering into the Palestinian Authority A areas (as designated in the Oslo accords).
>
> The warrant is very short (1 page, Hebrew) and states that the area is "closed": Israeli citizens as recognised by Israeli law, are forbidden from entering, and required to immediately leave if they are in that area. **People who are "not citizens of the area, who have a standing visa to be in Israel" are not allowed to enter area A as well. ("מי שאינו תושב האיזור ובידו אשרת כניסה בתוקף לישראל" which may refer to foreign nationals, the language is vague**)

So legally speaking the situation is not entirely clear. The military order itself is on shaky legal grounds and it's not being systematically enforced:

> The warrant was tested in Israeli courts and ruled to be one that can
> be enforced (i.e soldiers may prohibit entry for an Israeli citizen),
> though in April 2013 a [civil court ruled](http://www.haaretz.co.il/news/law/1.2004737) that civilians failing to
> comply with it are not to be arrested (after the fact).
>
> On the ground, de facto, Israeli Arabs are not stopped at the
> checkpoints and generally speaking, usually allowed to enter area A
> without hindrance. **Also tourists / foreign nationals are usually
> allowed in. So, almost always, only Israeli Jews are turned back.**

This means you should be okay, regardless of your current visa in Israel. If stopped by Israeli military personnel apologize and try again at another time. Also see our [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/safe-place-to-see-the-real-palestine-as-an-israeli-passport-holder?noredirect=1&lq=1) on visiting Palestine as an Israeli citizen.

P.S. A rough Google Translate of the linked military order from [October 2000](http://www.law.idf.il/Templates/GetFile/GetFile.aspx?FileName=XGF5b3NoLWRvY3NcdGFmcml0X2hha2lrYVx0emF2ZXlfc2dpcmF0X3NodGFoaW1cc2dpcmF0X3NoZXRhaF9lc3VyX2tuaXNhX2lzcmFlbGltX2V6dXJhLnBkZg%3D%3D&InfoCenterItem=true) can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6dbb8957321c8ff8c960ae77fc6e625).